# How do you access an attached property of a Silverlight object in C#?

Tags: c#, silverlight

Basically I'm trying to change the `Canvas.Left` property of an Ellipse Silverlight control in C#.  Here is how I'm accessing the control:

```
Ellipse c1 = this.FindName("Circle1") as Ellipse;
```

How would I then set the `Canvas.Left` property?

Thanks,

Jeff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer lies in Silverlights use of Dependancy Properties

c1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, value);

Answer (score 0):

something like this...

```
double left=50;
c1.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, left);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way
Canvas.SetLeft(c1,value)